# Transparent Keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

almost finished my App. All calculations, ..... are now working. 
As I have several Text Fields on the view and when I'm showing keyboard, I cannot see what I typing Field it is hidden by the keyboard.

Do you have a method for showing transparent keyboard then people will be able to see by transparency.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you just shift the view up while editing? Changing the keyboard will probably make Apple not allow your app. I suppose you could create your own keyboard from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the following code in your .m file for each view you want to add the transparent keyboard to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;

}
```

textField1 and textField2 are just examples. you need to add these 2 lines for each field. It's guaranteed way, I have 2 apps with these and just updated them 2 weeks ago and they were never rejected.

****You should change to the keyboard type you want.**

[image: semi-transparent keypad]

Answer (score 1):

You should read the ["Keyboard Management" section of the "Text, Web and Editing Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) in Apple documentation.

In the "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard" paragraph, they explains how to manage the keyboard properly and how to scroll your view so that the current text field is always visible and never hidden by the keyboard.

[image: Scrolling the keyboard]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Art/keyboard_adjust.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a transparent keyboard. You need to move your text field so that it is visible when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Can I reduce keyboard size ? Or even move to difference place ?

Comment: No you cant, you have to move your fields parent view to show them.